# Can I install Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit alongside Windows 8 32-bit?

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I am planning to dualboot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10. My Windows 8 is a 32-bit OS. Can I install Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit alongside it?

My processor is 64-bit capable and my laptop is a relatively new one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any problem, since each OS will live in an independent partition, and will not be aware of the other one, except for GRUB, which will know the number of OSs installed and the location of them, of course, and prompt you during startup, which OS you want to boot into.